# Возможность изменить константу(нет) или в одной области лежат разные значения

Tags: c++, visual-c++, память, const, const-cast

Решил поэкспериментировать с снятием const с переменной и получил очень интересный результат. Получается у нас в одной области памяти лежат разные данные? Кто объяснит что произошло.

```
int main()
{
    const int a = 5;

    const int* ptrA = &a;

    auto ptrA2 = const_cast<int*>(ptrA);

    *ptrA2 = 3;

    cout << "&a\t=\t" << &a << "\t a\t=\t" << a << endl;
    cout << "ptrA\t=\t" << ptrA << "\t *ptrA \t=\t" << *ptrA << endl;
    cout << "ptrA2\t=\t" << ptrA2 << "\t *ptrA2\t=\t" << *ptrA2 << endl;
```

}
[image: __]

Comment: Два слова: неопределенное поведение.

Comment: Грубо говоря, вы сказали `const a` и компилятор видит, что это 5. Дальше, всюду где встечается это имя он не лезет в память, а подставляет 5 (в машинные команды). Однако, всюду, где вы  обманув его, заставляете лезть в память, отведенную под `a` , он выбирает из нее новое значение. Вот и все. Т.о. `const` **это не настоящая константа**